# filling in columns with matching IDs from two dataframes in R

Tags: r

I have two dataframes (df1, df2). I want to fill in the AGE and SEX values from df1 to df2 conditioned on having the same ID between the two. I tried several ways using for-loop and checking subject ID match between the two data frame but I failed. The result should be as in the df3. I have a huge dataset, so I want a piece of code in R that can do this easily. I would appreciate your assistance in this. Thank you.

```
df1:
ID    AGE   SEX
90901   39  0
90902   28  0
90903   40  1

df2:
ID     AGE  SEX  Conc
90901   NA  NA    5
90901   NA  NA    10
90901   NA  NA    15
90903   NA  NA    30
90903   NA  NA    5
90902   NA  NA    2.45
90902   NA  NA    51
90902   NA  NA    1
70905   NA  NA    0.5

result:
df3:
ID     AGE  SEX  Conc
90901   39  0     5
90901   39  0     10
90901   39  0     15
90903   40  1    30
90903   40  1    5
90902   28  1    2.45
90902   28  0    51
90902   28  0     1
70905   NA  NA    0.5
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join data frames in R (inner, outer, left, right)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-data-frames-in-r-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: Thank you all! That is amazing:-) I hope I come to a point where I understand and play with the apply family functions. They are very useful but needs hard thinking. Would be great if some body guide me to some useful resources.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `match` with `lapply` for this.  If we iterate `[[` with matching on the `ID` column of each of the original data sets over a vector of names, we can get the desired result.

```
nm <- c("AGE", "SEX")
df2[nm] <- lapply(nm, function(x) df1[[x]][match(df2$ID, df1$ID)])
df2
#      ID AGE SEX  Conc
# 1 90901  39   0  5.00
# 2 90901  39   0 10.00
# 3 90901  39   0 15.00
# 4 90903  40   1 30.00
# 5 90903  40   1  5.00
# 6 90902  28   0  2.45
# 7 90902  28   0 51.00
# 8 90902  28   0  1.00
# 9 70905  NA  NA  0.50
```

Note that this is also quite a bit faster than `merge`.

Comment: Is there a way to apply this method so that it won't overwrite any non-NA values in df2$AGE and df2$SEX?

Comment: Out of nowhere, this solution saved me hours of search. Thanks.

Comment: This worked, but the initial dataframe had 250Mb and now has 485Gb...

Answer (score 8):

Try `merge(df1, df2, by = "id")`. This will merge your two data frames together. If your example is a good representation of your actual data, then you might want to go ahead and drop the age and sex columns from df2 before you merge.

```
df2$AGE <- NULL
df2$SEX <- NULL
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id")
```

If you need to keep rows from df2 even when you don't have a matching id in df1, then you do this:

```
df2 <- subset(df2, select = -c(AGE,SEX) )
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id", all.y = TRUE)
```

You can learn more about `merge` (or any r function) by typing `?merge()` in your r console.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr(v1.0.0)` approach, which only overwrites NA values in `df2`:

```
rows_patch(df2 %>%mutate(across(AGE:SEX,as.integer)),df1)

     ID AGE SEX  Conc
1 90901  39   0  5.00
2 90901  39   0 10.00
3 90901  39   0 15.00
4 90903  40   1 30.00
5 90903  40   1  5.00
6 90902  28   0  2.45
7 90902  28   0 51.00
8 90902  28   0  1.00
9 70905  NA  NA  0.50
```