# Matching and replacing factor values using id

Tags: r, data-manipulation, recode

I have two dataframes both of which contain the same variable and a unique id for each observation.

df.1 is a large dataset which contains missing values denoted by an NA. The values for those missing entries are contained within df.2 and I would like to replace the missings from df.1 with the values from df.2 by matching the id's.

I haven't been able to find a similar issue on here which takes into account them both being factor variables.

**To make things simpler: if the id's match - the missing value from df.1 should be replaced with the factor value from df.2.**

```
df.1 <- data.frame(id = c(334,440,501,2304,2500), 
                v1 = c("4 dogs",NA,"3 dogs",NA,"No dogs"))

df.2 <- data.frame(id = c(440,2304), 
                v2 = c("4 dogs","5 dogs"))
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check these, I think this has been answered.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5965698/merge-unequal-dataframes-and-replace-missing-rows-with-0) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25539326/filling-in-columns-with-matching-ids-from-two-dataframes-in-r)

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the same case. i'd like the code to simply match ids between the two variables and replace the values from df.2 to df.1. The ids only specify values which are missing in df.1.

Comment: Why do you need to keep them as both factor variables? Just convert to `character`.

Comment: `within(merge(df.1, df.2, all = TRUE), { V1 = pmax(as.character(v1), as.character(v2), na.rm = TRUE) ; rm(v1, v2)})`....

Comment: Ultimately I'd like all the data to be in factor form at the end as I would like to do further analysis using them in that class...

Comment: tricky question.

Comment: It's easy to convert back to factor at the end.

Comment: Yes but would it retain the same levels as it had at the beginning? If it originally had a level but it wasn't used as a value in the observations, then turning it into a character would mean it loses that level when its finally converted to a factor again?

Comment: @Gregor I would have preferred converting at end too.

Comment: So save the beginning levels! `init_levels = levels(df.1$v1) ... <all your code> ... result$v1 = factor(result$v1, levels = init_levels)`

Comment: @Gregor Yep I understand that and thank you for the code. I was just worried that since its a large amount of survey data, that any other meta-data information could have been lost from it similar to those levels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table` and `dplyr`:-

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
df <- left_join(df.1, df.2, by = "id")
setDT(df)
df[is.na(v1), v1 := v2]
df[, v2 := NULL]
```

You'll get the desired output:-

```
     id      v1
1:  334  4 dogs
2:  440  4 dogs
3:  501  3 dogs
4: 2304  5 dogs
5: 2500 No dogs
```

Till this point `id` would be numeric and `v1` would be factor. If you want `id` also to be converted to factor. You can do that using:-

```
df[, id := as.factor(id)]
```

Comment: Would the variable lose its factor type using this method?

Comment: So, `v1` would be factor. `id` would be numeric. If you want to make `id` again factor. You can use `df[, id := as.factor(id)]`. I'll add it in answer, if you want.

Comment: Apologies, ID was always numeric anyway and can remain numeric as its simply a Unique identifier. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, anyways I added it. If you need you can use it.

Comment: Having just used your code and taken a look at a summary of the newly created v1 variable. It seems 'NA' has been added as a factor for all the missing values in df1 which werent replaced...do you have a solution to turn them back into just missing values?

Comment: I guess this is how it was when you created `df.1`. NA were coming as factors.

Answer (score 2):

As @Gregor mentioned you can to convert df back to factors. The handy function here is `coalesce` function by @MrFlick. The solution is self-explanatory

```
library(dplyr)

df.1 %>%
  left_join(df.2, by = "id") %>%
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
  mutate(final = coalesce(v1, v2))  %>% mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
```

***output***

```
   id      v1     v2   final
1  334  4 dogs   <NA>  4 dogs
2  440    <NA> 4 dogs  4 dogs
3  501  3 dogs   <NA>  3 dogs
4 2304    <NA> 5 dogs  5 dogs
5 2500 No dogs   <NA> No dogs
```

store the above result in a variable(df), then check the `str(df)`

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id   : num  334 440 501 2304 2500
 $ v1   : Factor w/ 3 levels "3 dogs","4 dogs",..: 2 NA 1 NA 3
 $ v2   : Factor w/ 2 levels "4 dogs","5 dogs": NA 1 NA 2 NA
 $ final: Factor w/ 4 levels "3 dogs","4 dogs",..: 2 2 1 3 4
```

if you want to drop the `v1` and `v2` columns, just pipe the final result to `%>% select(id,final)`

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can join `df.1` and `df.2` to keep both `v1` and `v2` in the merged `data.frame`. The run logic to replace missing `v1` with value of `v2`.

```
library(dplyr)

df.1 <- data.frame(id = c(334,440,501,2304,2500), 
                   v1 = c("4 dogs",NA,"3 dogs",NA,"No dogs"))

df.2 <- data.frame(id = c(440,2304), 
                   v2 = c("4 dogs","5 dogs"))
#merge using left_join to keep all rows from df.1
final <- df.1 %>%
  left_join(df.2, by = "id")
#> final
#    id      v1     v2
#1  334  4 dogs   <NA>
#2  440    <NA> 4 dogs
#3  501  3 dogs   <NA>
#4 2304    <NA> 5 dogs
#5 2500 No dogs   <NA>

#Define a function to replace missing v1
replMissing <- function(x, y){
  ifelse(is.na(x), y, x )
}

#call replMissing function using mapply. Modified to handle factor
final$v1 <- as.factor(mapply(replMissing, as.character(final$v1), as.character(final$v2)))

#results is
#> final
#    id      v1     v2
#1  334  4 dogs   <NA>
#2  440  4 dogs 4 dogs
#3  501  3 dogs   <NA>
#4 2304  5 dogs 5 dogs
#5 2500 No dogs   <NA>
```

The `v2` column can be dropped now

Comment: Is there possible solution to then change them back to a factor and retain all the levels it originally had?

Comment: @dayleymart modified solution to handle `factor` value. Actually while calling `mapply` conversion needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` approach you have two solutions:

First solution:

```
library(dplyr)
df.1 <- data.frame(id = c(334,440,501,2304,2500), 
                   v1 = c("4 dogs",NA,"3 dogs",NA,"No dogs"),stringsAsFactors=F) 

df.2 <- data.frame(id = c(440,2304), 
                   v2 = c("4 dogs","5 dogs"),stringsAsFactors=F) %>% 
    rename(v1=v2)

df_mix <- bind_rows(df.1,df.2) %>% 
    drop_na(...=v1)
```

Second solution:

```
df.1 <- data.frame(id = c(334,440,501,2304,2500), 
                   v1 = c("4 dogs",NA,"3 dogs",NA,"No dogs"),stringsAsFactors=F)

df.2 <- data.frame(id = c(440,2304), 
                   v2 = c("4 dogs","5 dogs"),stringsAsFactors=F) 

df_mix <- left_join(df.1,df.2,by="id") %>% 
    mutate(v1=case_when(
        is.na(v1) ~ v2,
        !is.na(v1) ~ v1
    )) %>% 
    select(1:2)
```

PS: I prefer to laod strings as character vectors